# What my Regex should be?

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I want to control my string with regex which should has chars between a and z (It can be upper case ) and ";" char. (Only a-z and ";" with whitespaces). What my regex should be?

Comment: Document yourself, try to do it, and if you have any trouble come back explaining what have you tried and what is your trouble. Helping you is not the same that doing your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the RE engine, but you'd be looking for something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z;\s]*$
```

or use `+` instead of `*` if you need at least one character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:
    [a-zA-Z;\s]*

Answer (score 0):

this regex should do it /[a-zA-Z;\s]*/